# Listening for a radio button to be checked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I have a submission form that requires at least one radio button to be checked. I already have a code there to get the value of the radio button:

```
let myQuery = document.querySelector('input[name="#myName"]:checked').value;
```

If this returns any value (it's a string of text) then can I do:

```
document.getElementById("#ButtonID").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

I have the submit button currently "disabled" so removing the attribute works perfectly to allow the users to submit after they have checked a radio button.

How do I get that in to this querySelector? I already have a set of variables being taken from the .value for the radio button the user pushed.

Thanks kindly :)

Comment: could you provide the html for the elements

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide your html template, I'm assuming something like this:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input[name="Name"]');

input.addEventListener("change", () => {
 console.log(input.value)
 document.getElementById("ButtonId").removeAttribute("disabled");
});
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Please click on the Name:</p>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="Name" value="Name">
    <label for="Name"> Name</label> 
  </fieldset>
  
  <button id="ButtonId" disabled>
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

So what you're looking for, presumably is [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Hi, can you provide some more details? What exactly isn't working? What have you tried so far? What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

Building off of the other answers, we can create a form where no radio buttons are selected by default but a selection is required for form submission:

The HTML:

```
<h1>test form</h1>
<form>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="a-radio-group" value="first" />
      first
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="a-radio-group" value="second" />
      second
    </label>
    <label> 
      <input type="radio" name="a-radio-group" value="third" />
      third
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="button" disabled>submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The JS:

```
document.querySelector('form')
  .addEventListener('click', 
    function(event) {
      const checkedRadioInputs =
        document.querySelectorAll('input[name="a-radio-group"]:checked');

        if(checkedRadioInputs.length) {
          document
            .querySelector('button')
            .removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
    }
  );
```

You probably already have some of this in place but I want to elaborate on three parts:

- First, radio buttons are meant to be used in groups and all radios in that group need to have the same 'name' attribute. With this in place, if the user selects an option, it will 'uncheck' all other radio options and 'check' the newly selected option. More on [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).
- I'm setting a 'click' listener on the parent form element so we can monitor changes to the whole form. If you don't have a parent form element then you'll have to add onChange handlers to each radio input and track the state. I think the form way is simpler and would avoid the latter approach if possible.
- If you use querySelectorAll then you get back an array and you can just test against the array's length: if the length is 0 then nothing is selected. More on [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 0):

Usually , as the normal use of radio button , we select 1 button by default.
But if you want it to be not selected initially then ,

```js
function hello() {
            // body...
            let button1 = document.getElementsByName("a").checked;
            console.log(button1);

            document.getElementById("gn").disabled=false;
        }
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="a" onclick="hello()">daknd<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="a" onclick="hello()">hmm
        
        <button id="gn" type="submit" disabled>hmm</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I guess I can just select one by default. That's not the end of the world to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, you made one mistake by using '#' in getElementById() method.
We need '#' sign in jQuery but in javascript it takes the ID name only.

```
document.getElementById("#ButtonID").removeAttribute("disabled");



<script>

function checkStatus(obj)
{
  
  if(obj.value != "")
  {
     document.getElementById("button").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}

</script>


<form id="" name="" action="" method="">

       <li><input type="radio" name="a" id="RAD_1" value="RAD_1" 
       onclick="checkStatus(this);">Hello 1</input></li>

       <li><input type="radio" name="a" id="RAD_2" value="RAD_2" 
      onclick="checkStatus(this);">Hello 2</input></li>

      <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Submit" disabled> 
</input>
</form>
```

Comment: The # was only for display purposes, not actually in the code. To remind me to put in the respective value when it comes around to coding it.